# Structural property of DFAs/NFAs accepting LTL-definable languages

Tags: dfa, linear-temporal-logic, nfa

I consider LTL on finite words. In this context, there are a couple of nice equivalence results for a language `L`:

- `L` is LTL-definable (i.e., there exists an LTL formula `phi` such that `L` is the set of all words satisfying `phi`)
- `L` is FO[<, Succ]-definable
- `L` is star-free

However, I am looking for a simple (sufficient) condition on the **structure of a DFA**, let us call it `A`, that guarantees that the language `L(A)` accepted by `A` is indeed LTL-definable. I am aware that `L(A)` is LTL-definable if and only if the syntactic monoid of `A` is group-free, but this monoid is too large to compute in many cases.

Is there a "simpler", preferably structural property on DFAs/NFAs that guarantees that the accepted language is expressible by an LTL formula?

Comment: Deciding whether a DFA recognizes an aperiodic language is PSPACE-complete (see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759190075D). So I doubt that there is an affirmative answer to your question: any structural property you may find would be PSPACE-complete to decide.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_finite_state_automaton